# Snowflakes in C++

Tags: c++, beginner, sfml, c++20

I've started learning C++ using Microsoft Visual Studio. I'm decided to create a simple GUI program that creates a "snowflake" wherever the user clicks on the screen. Seeing as how this is my first C++ program, I would greatly appreciate feedback on any aspect of my code.

**snowflakes.cpp**

```
// Includes //
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <iostream>

// Declare function //
void snowflakes();

/**
 * Creates a snowflake where the user clicks on the screen.
**/
void snowflakes() {

    const int WIDTH = 1280;
    const int HEIGHT = 960;

    sf::RenderWindow render_window(
        sf::VideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT), "Snowflakes"
    );
    sf::Event event;
    sf::Image image;
    sf::Mouse mouse;
    image.create(WIDTH, HEIGHT, sf::Color::Black);

    sf::Texture texture;

    while (render_window.isOpen()) {
        while (render_window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::EventType::Closed) {
                render_window.close();
            } else if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed) {
                int mouse_x = mouse.getPosition(render_window).x;
                int mouse_y = mouse.getPosition(render_window).y;
                std::cout << mouse_x << " " << mouse_y << std::endl;

                image.setPixel(mouse_x, mouse_y, sf::Color::White);

                // Get random size of snowflake //

                int size = (rand() % 20) + 10;

                for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
                    image.setPixel(mouse_x + i, mouse_y, sf::Color::White);
                    image.setPixel(mouse_x - i, mouse_y, sf::Color::White);
                    image.setPixel(mouse_x, mouse_y + i, sf::Color::White);
                    image.setPixel(mouse_x, mouse_y - i, sf::Color::White);
                    image.setPixel(mouse_x + i, mouse_y + i, sf::Color::White);
                    image.setPixel(mouse_x - i, mouse_y - i, sf::Color::White);
                    image.setPixel(mouse_x + i, mouse_y - i, sf::Color::White);
                    image.setPixel(mouse_x - i, mouse_y + i, sf::Color::White);
                }
            }
        }

        texture.loadFromImage(image);
        sf::Sprite dots(texture);

        render_window.clear();
        render_window.draw(dots);
        render_window.display();
    }

}

int main() {
    // Start program //
    snowflakes();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't sfml need some initialization anymore?

Comment: Three loops deep is a bit much (+ a branch)... C++ devs may not like the Egyptian braces. I'd also like a `drawSnowflake` method in there. The how is clearly well done, but the **what** seems a bit missing in action.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ apparently, no. I was surprised as well :)

Comment: @Linny At some point in your learning, and I'm guessing fairly soon, you'll come to classes in C++. You code is getting *near* to where a class might not be a bad idea..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to C++.  Nice and readable C++ code!

I'm not familiar with SFML, but here are my suggestions about improving the code:

- When you get familiar with C++, comments like these can be deleted: `// Includes //` `// Declare function //` `// Start program //`.
- You don't need to declare a function first if you define it immediately after.
- These constants can be made `constexpr`:

  ```
  const int WIDTH = 1280;
  const int HEIGHT = 960;
  ```

  Also, `ALL_CAPS` names are generally reserved for macros.  Constants can use `lower_case` names instead.
- This `if` statement (note that `::EventType` is sometimes included but sometimes omitted):

  ```
  if (event.type == sf::Event::EventType::Closed) {
      // ...
  } else if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed) {
      // ...
  }
  ```

  can be replaced by a `switch` statement since [`event.type` happens to be an enum](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Event.php#af41fa9ed45c02449030699f671331d4a).  Also, since you are using [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20), you can use the `using enum` feature to simplify your code if your compiler supports it:

  ```
  switch (event.type) {
      using enum sf::Event::EventType;
  case Closed:
      // ...
      break;
  case MouseButtonPressed:
      // ...
      break;
  }
  ```
- This:

  ```
  int mouse_x = mouse.getPosition(render_window).x;
  int mouse_y = mouse.getPosition(render_window).y;
  std::cout << mouse_x << " " << mouse_y << std::endl;
  ```

  can be simplified with structured bindings since [`Vector2i`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Vector2.php), the return type of `getPosition`, seems to have public members.  (I almost wrote "don't use `std::endl`," but then I realized that flushing semantics is appropriate here!)

  ```
  auto [x, y] = mouse.getPosition(render_window);
  std::cout << x << ' ' << y << std::endl;
  ```
- The rendering code deserves a separate function:

  ```
  image.setPixel(mouse_x, mouse_y, sf::Color::White);

  // Get random size of snowflake //

  int size = (rand() % 20) + 10;

  for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
      image.setPixel(mouse_x + i, mouse_y, sf::Color::White);
      image.setPixel(mouse_x - i, mouse_y, sf::Color::White);
      image.setPixel(mouse_x, mouse_y + i, sf::Color::White);
      image.setPixel(mouse_x, mouse_y - i, sf::Color::White);
      image.setPixel(mouse_x + i, mouse_y + i, sf::Color::White);
      image.setPixel(mouse_x - i, mouse_y - i, sf::Color::White);
      image.setPixel(mouse_x + i, mouse_y - i, sf::Color::White);
      image.setPixel(mouse_x - i, mouse_y + i, sf::Color::White);
  }
  ```

  Also, consider using the `<random>` library instead of `rand`:

  ```
  std::mt19937_64 engine{std::random_device{}()}; // global or static
  ```

  then

  ```
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist{10, 29}; // clearer than (rand() % 20) + 10
  int size = dist(eng);
  ```

Comment: Thanks, L. F.! Unfortunately my current compiler doesn't support `using enum`, but all your other suggestions are great. Thanks for the review!

Comment: @L. F. Is it worth creating a snowflake class ? And have a draw method () ? The usual caveats about multiparadigm language and all that. Just a thought..

Comment: @Lozminda Since the snowflake doesn’t have any state, I don’t think having a Snowflake class is worthwhile.